# error 1009: cannot access method of a null object reference

Tags: apache-flex

I am doing a flex blazedDS project via spring and hibernate. I have error 1009 "cannot access property or method of a null object reference" when I switch between canvases of a view stack.
How can I avoid this error any help would be appreciated.

```
<mx:VBox height="244.55" y="219.45" width="624.01514" x="10">
 <mx:LinkBar dataProvider="{myViewStack}" enabled="true"  activate="true"/>
  <mx:ViewStack id = "myViewStack" width="624" height="212" enabled="true">
   <mx:Canvas id="canvas3" label="Financement" enabled="true" enterState="true" >
  <mx:Label x="38" y="10" text="Code Fin."/>
      <mx:Label x="19" y="36" text="Fond propre" enabled="true"/>
  <mx:TextInput x="119" y="34" id="fondprofin"/>
  <mx:TextInput x="119" y="8" id="codefin"/>



     <mx:Label x="100" y="10" text="*" width="11" color="#E0391E"/>
   </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Canvas id="canvas1" label="Investissement" enabled="true" enterState="true" >
  </canvas>
```

Comment: The only sensible answer one can give to this question is: don't create nullpointers. Unfortunately you don't provide sufficient information (in the form of the code that throws the error for instance) to say anything more. Please read this guide on how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: I have sent you some of the code please some help. when i click on canvas "Financement" then canvas "Investissement" I have the error 1009 as listed above. I think that the canevases are by defult nullpointer. How do I make them active?

Comment: @yosrab Please post the actionscript code, i can't help you with the mxml code, the error is not here.

Comment: If this is the exact code, it shouldn't compile: the closing tag of the second Canvas is incorrect. Also `activate="true"` and `enterState="true"` will not have any effect: these are not properties, but event handlers. It's as if you'd write `function onEnterState(event):void { true; }`. They shouldn't throw any errors though, they're just useless.

Comment: I voted to close this. If you're using the debug Flash player, the error message you get includes the line number and class name that the error occurs on. You need to show that code so we can help. Showing us code that doesn't compile also is not helpful (it just makes us nitpick on things that are usually not the problem). You can edit your question and include the code that is throwing the exception.